# Python loops, need some advice

Tags: python, loops

i trying to create a small program usign python and i need some help about python loops.
this small program will automates a fairly boring repetitive task.

I use module : selenium, time and pyautogui

here is the piece of code that i want to repeat until it no longer finds a certain element on the web page :

```
btnOptions = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div")
btnOptions.click()
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press("down", presses=10)
pyautogui.press("enter")
time.sleep(1)
btn_move = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]")
btn_move.click()
```

as long as the btn_option is found, the program must continue otherwise it must stop.

I can't find a solution, if anyone can help me it would be very appreciated.
thanks a lot

i tried several loops but every time i get an error of course, I'm just new to coding in python :/

Comment: show us what loops have you tried and the error messages. it would be helpfull if you could show the web page in question

Comment: in another small program i was able to make a loop using For but i was using another module (BeautifulSoup), I can't adapt the loop with selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a similar task. You may try this:

```py
while True:
    try:
        btnOptions = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div")
        btnOptions.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press("down", presses=10)
        pyautogui.press("enter")
        time.sleep(1)
        btn_move = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div[1]")
        btn_move.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break
```

Comment: now i got this error : except NoSuchElementException:
NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined

Comment: lol, of course... i need this : from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

Comment: no more error about exception but the program still stops at the first round

Comment: it is working mate!! thanks A LOT ! btnOptions line was too long, reformated by pycharm and all is good now, YOU ARE THE MAN !! thank u